# Colorbox close in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, colorbox

We have a colourbox opening on an `<a>` tag loading a reasonably large chunk of stuff into it. It's working okay in major browsers, but when you close the colourbox using IE7, you get a script timeout warning message.

I've tried hooking into the `onCleanup` and other methods to see if that can help, but it seems that IE has trouble unloading and closing the window.

Has anyone experienced this or had similar issues? A workaround might be loading all the content first and displaying inline, but I'd rather just fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

author here.  I haven't seen any other reports for this specific problem.  It could be that you are generating JS errors which would be interfering with further JS execution.  Maybe it's IE7 specific, or maybe IE7 is just choking on the error while other browser's handle it more gracefully.  My suggestion would be to post a link demonstrating the problem as it is probably something that is specific to your site.

Comment: As we were under pressure to deliver for the client, we've coded a workaround to make the data smaller. It was delivering an html table of 1126 rows, at about 96kb of file. Seemed to be in both IE7+8, using both `<a>` and picking inline content from a `div`. Thanks for the reply Jack! Keep up the great work! :)  Implementation is here, http://www.leatherheadfood.com/member-services-member - Click 'Full Membership List'

Answer (score 0):

Put a var definition just before the container call in the js file
it will be like

```
var container=$(this);
```